# Where to find the password reset mailable in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to use the reset password mailable in my project because the admin is the one creating users for me,

What am I suppose to do to use the password reset mailable in this controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'address_id' => 'required',
        'name'       => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'      => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'POBox'      => ['required', 'min:6', 'max:6'],
        'role_id'    => 'required',
    ]);

    $quickpass = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10)), 0, 10);

    $newuser = User::create([
        'address_id' => $request->address_id,
        'name'       => $request->name,
        'email'      => $request->email,
        'POBox'      => $request->POBox,
        'password'   => Hash::make($quickpass),
        'role_id'    => $request->role_id,
    ]);

    Mail::to($newuser->email)
        ->send(new NewUserPassReset(
            $request->input('name'),
            $request->input('email')
        ));

    return back()->with('message', 'The user has been created and a password reset email has been sent to them.');
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 6.1